# Flutter map_view center to user location

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I'm using the [map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/map_view/latest/) plugin to build a map in my Fluter app. I'm following the example, but I would like to initialize the map to the user current location without hardcoding the coordinates.
I have been digging into the docs and the Github issues and found [this](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/28), but I can't understand how to apply it.

The map is initialized this way:

```
mapView.show(
    new MapOptions(
        mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
        showUserLocation: true,
        initialCameraPosition: new CameraPosition(
            new Location(45.5235258, -122.6732493), 14.0),
        title: "Recently Visited"),
    toolbarActions: [new ToolbarAction("Close", 1)]);
```

Get notified when the map is ready

How can I use this code to set the position of the map?

```
mapView.onLocationUpdated.listen((location) => myUserLocation = location);
```

This is the entirety of my code:

```
Location myUserLocation = null;

class NuMapView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
_NuMapViewState createState() => new _NuMapViewState();
}




class _NuMapViewState extends State<NuMapView> {
  static String apiKey = "mykey";

  MapView mapView;
  CameraPosition cameraPosition;
  var compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
  var staticMapProvider = new StaticMapProvider(apiKey);
  Uri staticMapUri;




  @override
  void initState(){
      print("dentro init state\n");

  mapView = new MapView();
  mapView.onLocationUpdated.listen((location) {
    print("cacchissime\n");
    if (myUserLocation == null){
      print("user location non null\n");
      myUserLocation = location;
      showMap();
    }
    else {
      print("user location è nullo!!\n");
    }


  } );

  super.initState();
    }



    bool ready = false;

  List<Marker> _markers = new List<Marker>();


    });
  }





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Text("ciao")
      ),

    );
  }

  showMap() {
    mapView.show(
        new MapOptions(
            mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
            showUserLocation: true,
            showMyLocationButton: true,
            showCompassButton: true,
            initialCameraPosition: new CameraPosition(
                new Location(myUserLocation.latitude, myUserLocation.longitude), 35.0),
            hideToolbar: false,
            title: "Cerca sulla mappa"),

        );
    StreamSubscription sub = mapView.onMapReady.listen((_) {
      mapView.setMarkers(_markers);

    });
    compositeSubscription.add(sub);
    sub = mapView.onLocationUpdated.listen((location) {
      print("Location updated $location");
    });
    compositeSubscription.add(sub);
    sub = mapView.onTouchAnnotation
        .listen((annotation) => print("annotation ${annotation.id} tapped"));
    compositeSubscription.add(sub);

    sub = mapView.onCameraChanged.listen((cameraPosition) =>
        this.setState(() => this.cameraPosition = cameraPosition));
    compositeSubscription.add(sub);


  }
```

Comment: could you put the code when you initialize the mapview ?

Comment: Is the same one as the doc, but I will update my question

Answer (score 3):

Ok, based on the information that you posted, you can do something like this:

```
  //state class variable    
  Location myUserLocation;


      @override
      void initState() {
         mapView.onLocationUpdated.listen((location) {
            if (myUserLocation == null){
                myUserLocation = location;
                _loadMap();
            }

         } );
        super.initState();
      }


      _loadMap(){
          mapView.show(
           new MapOptions(
              mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
              showUserLocation: true,
              initialCameraPosition: new CameraPosition(
                  new Location(myUserLocation.latitude, myUserLocation.longitude), 14.0),
              title: "Recently Visited"),
          toolbarActions: [new ToolbarAction("Close", 1)]);
      }
```

First, after `initState` you can get your current location and call showMap with your location.

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't go inside onLocationUpdated and the map doesn't get loaded..

Comment: could you give us more information? does the app ask for permissions about location? could you update your code in the question? does the gps is enabled?

Comment: permission are asked, gps is enabled. I wrote both the variable and the initState method override inside my ClassViewState method. I wrote a debug print in the initState method: it enters the method but just doesn't go inside the .listen part...

Comment: Just updated the code, i cut out some other methods not useful

Comment: you are listening twice :   sub = mapView.onLocationUpdated.listen((location) {
      print("Location updated $location");
    });  remove that

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: did you get any error on the console log?  are you testing on simulator? android/ios ? device ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177759/discussion-between-andrea-grippi-and-diegoveloper).

Answer (score 3):

This code what you need (I have displayed the full code so you can try it directly):

Note, you need to install [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) and [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) and [permission](https://pub.dev/packages/permission) packages to project before run this code.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:permission/permission.dart';

void main() => runApp(TestMap());

class TestMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestMapState createState() => _TestMapState();
}

class _TestMapState extends State<TestMap> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //To Require Permission
    Permission.openSettings;

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Google Maps Demo',
      home: MapSample(),
    );
  }
}

class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> _mapPolylines = {};
  int _polylineIdCounter = 1;

  static double latitude_current = 31.9414246;
  static double longitude_current = 35.8880857;

  void _GetDeviceLocation() async {
    var location = new Location();
    location.changeSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.HIGH,
      distanceFilter: 0,
      interval: 100,
    );
    location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      latitude_current = currentLocation.latitude;
      longitude_current = currentLocation.longitude;
      _goToTheLake();
    });
  }



  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static final CameraPosition _kLake = CameraPosition(
      bearing: 60.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(latitude_current, longitude_current),
      tilt: 80.440717697143555,
      zoom: 18.151926040649414);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Maps"),
        actions: <Widget>[IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: _GetDeviceLocation)],
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(latitude_current, longitude_current),
          zoom: 14.4746,
        ),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          _GetDeviceLocation();
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_mapPolylines.values),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        label: Text('Drive Mode'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    _GetDeviceLocation();
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(_kLake));

  }
}
```

Comment: i'm using your answer to load location in a map,the map animation is slow and takes forever to load.my connection is fast

Comment: fixed it.if you set default values for latitude_current and  longitude_current it misbehaves

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution using GeoLocator plugin...
try this code..

```
  _animateToUser() async {
    Geolocator().getCurrentPosition().then((currloc) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = currloc;
      });
    });

    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
      zoom: 17.0,
    )));
  }
```

in google maps part...

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude), zoom: 17),
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      mapType: _currentMapType,
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
    ),
  ],
);
```

hope than helps!